# Programmatic copy and paste XML Node in MS Word Document?

Tags: python, xml, ms-word, mailmerge, python-docx

I'm trying to generate a bunch of MS Word Mergefeilds based on a slew of variable I have. After looking around it looks like the best solution is to open a word document with one Mergefeild as an XML file, find that field and copy it and then replace the text within the new variable names. Right now I'm stuck on the copy paste part and will tackle the replacement part in a bit. Please note I do not want to actually run a mail merge, just generate a bunch of mergefields.

Here's my code:

```
def check_element_is(element, type_char):
    word_schema = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'
    return element.tag == '{%s}%s' % (word_schema,type_char)

zfile = zipfile.ZipFile("C:TEST.docx")
# return the xml
filexml = zfile.read("word/document.xml")

my_etree = etree.fromstring(filexml)
etree.tostring(my_etree,pretty_print=True)

for node in my_etree.iter(tag=etree.Element):
    print node
    if check_element_is(node, 'fldSimple'):  ## Finds the Mergefeild node.
        dupe = copy.deepcopy(node)

my_etree.append(dupe)  ## I'd like this directly below the other mergefield node

zout = zipfile.ZipFile("C:Test_OUT.docx", 'w')
zout.writestr('word/document.xml', 'cool')
zout.close()
```

My mind is kind of fried on this, so I apologize if I'm not making sense.

Main inspiration was from this: [`docx_mailmerge.py`](https://gist.github.com/vzvenyach/38d1fb78d95f1ae1cfdc#file-docx_mailmerge-py) script
as well as other copy/paste xml questions on Stack overflow. I've also played with python-docx but it doesn't seem to fit the bill.

Comment: My brain is fried too so I'm not sure this is helpful, but whenever I want to manipulate word files I use the module `docx`  https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Yes, I hear you. I've been playing around with python-docx but I can't find any merge-field functionality. But if it comes down to it I guess I can just create and populate tables in using the python-docx table functionality, which might actually be the way to do it...

Comment: Just use minidom if document structure is trivial. Otherwise this is possible to take a look at xml file and figure out how to manipulate it as text file. For example,  you can prepare document.xml template with replacement field for mergefields and then just format string and zip it in docx.